# Inno Setup - inconsistent (preprocessor / debugger) behavior for string variable with defined symbol inside

Tags: windows, delphi, inno-setup

I found this very strange behavior when running my script:

When I hover mouse over variable **ConfigPath**: string; I can see the *correct* value.
However hovering over symbol **{#EPIC_ID}** shows me *wrong* value (saying Internal Error in English).

When I save the preprocessed script the value is correct:

> ConfigPath :=
> 'c:\ProgramData\Epic\EpicGamesLauncher\Data\Manifests\12C916CC456AD69CAD0B65898515C92A.item';

And the weirdest part is that **Log** (line 177) says just

> Reading ""

Like the variable ConfigPath is empty string (which is not!).

This is not happening all the time, it is random and I could not find a way how to reproduce it with 100% accuracy.

Can anybody explain this or reproduce? This may be some internal error how the symbols are expanded but even in that case the ConfigPath string should be not empty.

[image: Inno]

File **Main.iss** (the rest of the file does not matter):

```
#define EPIC_ID         "12C916CC456AD69CAD0B65898515C92A.item"

#if EPIC_ID
   #include "EpicHelper.iss"
#endif

[Setup]
...
[Code]
```

File **EpicHelper.iss** (the rest of the file does not matter):

```
<event('InitializeSetup')>
function InitializeSetupParseConfig(): Boolean;
var
  Json: string;
  ConfigPath: string;

begin
  Result := True;
  ConfigPath := 'c:\ProgramData\Epic\EpicGamesLauncher\Data\Manifests\{#EPIC_ID}';

  if (FileExists(ConfigPath) = false) then
  begin
     Log(Format('File not found: "%s"', [ConfigPath]));
     Exit;
  end;
  
  Log(Format('Reading "%s"', [ConfigPath]));
end;
```

Comment: I guess that debugger simply considers all `{...}` as constants and is not aware that the `{#...}` is actually a preprocessor syntax. + I cannot reproduce the logging problem.