# Inno Setup doesn't expand constant in inline {reg:}

Tags: inno-setup

During install I try to copy existing files from a folder defined in the registry. I use some user constants to find this folder.

Yet the constant doesn't seem to be expanded (is that a word?) and get the error `unknown constant '#RegKey'`.

Is there a way around this or do I have to code something in Pascal?

```
#define Version "2.0"
#define RegKey "MyExe v" + Version

[Setup]
// various stuff

[Files]
Source: {reg:HKLM64\SOFTWARE\MyCompanyData\{#RegKey},Path|\MyCompanyData\MyExe v1.0}\*; DestDir: {app}; Flags:external recursesubdirs onlyifdoesntexist
```

Comment: I do not get any *"unknown constant '#RegKey'"* when I try your script. When do you get it? On compile time or on install time? We probably need more details.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl when compiling or running goes without error, because it falls back to the default `\MyCompanyData\MyExe v1.0`. I also see that in the resulting actions. When I add a breakpoint and hove rover the statement, it shows the error message

Comment: That's actually an irrelevant glitch of the IDE: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75043027/850848#comment132428795_75043027 – When I test your script it works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Ib5.png – So again, we need more details.

Comment: So sorry, pebkac, typing mistake in reg key :( And got deceived by the above mentioned glitch in the IDE. Thanks Martin for your help

Comment: Please delete your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So sorry, pebkac, typing mistake in reg key :( And got deceived by the above mentioned glitch in the IDE [Inno Setup - inconsistent (preprocessor / debugger) behavior for string variable with defined symbol inside](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75043027/850848#comment132428795_75043027)

Thanks Martin for your help